# How can I change the Jenkins port from 8080 to any other port?

Tags: linux, jenkins, localhost, port, ubuntu-16.04

I want to change the default localhost port from 8080 to any other for jenkins.
I am using Ubuntu 16.04.

Answer (score 1):

You can go to /etc/default/jenkins and add --httpPort=9999 or whatever port to JENKINS_ARGS.

Then you should restart Jenkins with sudo service jenkins restart.

OR

In /etc/default/jenkins  change the JENKINS_PORT= variable to whatever port you want. Restart jenkins, and it should be running on your desired port.

Comment: Failed to restart je kins.service: Unit jenkins.service not found

Comment: Yes i have tried both of them and same error is coming.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is for centos.
To change the port you need to update `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` file. Here you can find
`JENKINS_PORT="8080"` variable declared. Just update this port.

Answer (score 0):

This questions already has been asked 1 or 2 times on the internet. Maybe just use the search on this website...

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9090
```

or

```
java -jar jenkins.war --httpsPort=9090
```

Comment: Error: Unable to access jarfile jenkins.war

Comment: How's your Jenkins started? Manually or by the system? Please post the current command.

Comment: like I followed digital oceans guide to install jenkins and now when I go to localhost/8080 on my browser the jenkin page is up.

Comment: On the Debian default (apt) install you can open the file /etc/default/jenkins with a text editor and change HTTP_PORT to whatever you want.

Then you should restart Jenkins with "sudo service jenkins restart"

Comment: Failed to restart jenkns.service: Unit Jenkins.service not found this error is coming what to do now?

Answer (score 0):

use sudo java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=8979

Comment: It shows Error: unable to access jarfile jenkins.war

Comment: check the jarfile permissions

Comment: How to do that?

Comment: using chmod in linux you can check the permissions of the file. have you run the command using "sudo"

Comment: Yes I used sudo

Comment: permissions of a file can be checked using "ls -la".

Comment: Now after that what to check?

Comment: can you tell what permissions does it have

Answer (score 0):

There is another solution for **Linux** systems that mentioned in Jenkins Documentation [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/installing/linux/)

If Jenkins fails to start because a port is in use, run:

```
systemctl edit jenkins
```

and add the following:

```
[Service]
Environment="JENKINS_PORT=8081"
```

This will change the port from 8080 to 8081

Answer (score -1):

To change Default Port of Jenkins in Windows while using jenkins.war use java -jar jenkins.war --httpPort=9999.

I have created a small [Video](https://youtu.be/qH2gmXZNtUg)